# How to write symbols to file in scilab

Tags: matlab, scilab

I'm working on **symbolic toolkit**. Trying to solve some equations and that's a long string of **symbols** such as x= a1+a2^3+b0*b1... upto 80,000(80k) characters. 
So I needed to put that in file.
*mputstr()* ans other wrting functions are not working since they are symbols.
Error is thrown as: not a string or specified format.

Does any method can help to bring down the variable to file. 
code is :

```
    Syms aa ab ac
    z=ab^6*ac^6*ad^3*ba^3*bg^3*bh^3+3*aa^4*ab^6*ac^6*ad^4*ba^4*bg^2*bh^2+3*aa^5*ab^6*ac^6*ad^5*ba^5*bg*bh+aa^6*ab^6*ac^6*ad^6*ba^6

    mputstr({char(z)},fd)
    >>error 10000 
    >>char: Wrong type for input argument: Cell expected.
    at line      95 of function char called by :  


    mputstr(z,fd)
    >> !--error 999 
    >mputstr: Wrong type for input argument #1: A string expected.

    p=string(z)

    mputstr(p,fd) 
    >>!--error 999 
    >mputstr: Wrong type for input argument #1: A string expected.


    mfprintf("%s",z) 
    >>    !--error 246 
    >>Function not defined for given argument type(s),
      check arguments or define function %c_mfprintf for overloading. ..
```

Comment: Its a *string* of symbols? A string is ASCII characters, it doesnt matter what character it contains. Are you sure it is a *string*

Comment: by string of symbols I meant, Its a long apha numeric symbolic expression..:      
 + a1  a2  a3  a4  b1  b2  b5  + 2 a1  a2  a3  a4  b1  b2  b5  + a1 a2  a3  a4  b1  b2  b5  + a1 a2 a3  a4  b1  b2  b5

Comment: But is it of type `char`? Because that is a string. Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: I had given @Ander...code block has been added

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a symbolic equation x:

```
syms a b c 
x = a + b * c
```

Here, x denotes a symbolic variable, so you cannot directly write it to a file. You need to convert it to a character array first. So you should be using something like

```
fd = mopen( this_file, "wt" );
mputstr( char(x), fd );
mclose( fd );
```

Comment: here x is a bit complex term , so i converted it to string using string(x) then tried to write with the solution you gave then it is showing error : "CELL EXPECTED" and even if I'm directly trying to use it is throwing same error..

Comment: If it expects a cell, then you should try mputstr( { char(x) } )

Comment: In any case, please update your question to show what you are trying, along with a minimum working example.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the fact that you must also give the file handle... in case that wasn't obvious..

Comment: Yes because you say 'char(z)'. You should have 'char(x)'. I am assuming that you have some other variable called z that is causing this to crash.

Comment: no no, sorry for inconvenience ...that 'x' is typing mistake its 'z'

Comment: From the first error, it seems that fd is not correctly defined. Are you getting it from mopen?

Comment: yes fd is from mpoen `fd=mpoen("file",'w')` . fd has no issues other string and char are getting printed in the file .

Comment: The one thing I did not see you try was 'mputstr( char(x), fd );' Does that fail as well?

Comment: yes as I told you earlier , It was showing same error `cell expected`..!!

Comment: The thing that does not make sense is that you say that you can write other strings to the file. char(x) is a string though. So if you try writing it to the file just like any other string, then it should work. If it doesn't then you either closed your file handle fd before trying to write char(x) or fd is not what you think it is. You do not have the complete code above so I cannot debug it based on the information you provide.

Comment: That is the strange thing em trying to figure out too. Other strings are getting written to file. Since We are dealing with symbols, this is where scilab is giving issues. `char(x)` `'x' represents a symbols` that is where problem is. If we write `mputstr("abc",fd)` abc will get printed. Even `mfprinf("%s","abc")` is working. Only fail is when symbols are involved. Down casting 'x' to string using `p=string(x)` and writing afterwards is even not working !!

Comment: Anyways not an issue thanx for suggestions :)

Comment: In your code, what are the outputs of class('abc') and class(char(x))? If those are the same, then it should not matter.

Comment: sorry I din't get `class` is this any function you want me to examine ../

Answer (score 0):

I think that @bremen_matt's answer is the good one, but with a modification.

If your "Syms" variables are something complex so *char()* and *string()* cannot be used, why you are not creating your own conversion function?

Please, see below my modification of @bremen_matt example:

```
syms a b c 
x = a + b * c 

fd = mopen( this_file, "wt" );
mputstr( syms_to_string(x), fd );
mclose( fd );
```

The *syms_to_string()* is returning a string of the information that you would like to print of the symbol *x*, and same function could be used to print other symbols (e.g. *a*). Of course, the *syms_to_string()* function could be better defined using [overloading](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/overloading.html).